# Error creating indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, indexed-view

I have problem with a counting column in my view.

```
SELECT ColumnC, ColumnA % ColumnB AS ModuloColAColB, COUNT_BIG(*) AS cBig FROM dbo.T1
GROUP BY ColumnC, ModuloColAColB
```

Query is similar to this MSDN example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

When I try to compile view I received error message like: 
"invalid column name ModuloColAColB"

So I change group by column names:

```
SELECT ColumnC, ColumnA % ColumnB AS ModuloColAColB,
COUNT_BIG(*) AS cBig FROM dbo.T1
GROUP BY ColumnC, ColumnA, ColumnB
```

View is compiling correctly but when I try to add index I receive the error:

```
"Cannot create the clustered index 'px_test' on view 'l' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column.
Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list"
```

When I remove " ColumnA % ColumnB AS ModuloColAColB" all works fine.

Database version: SQL server 2005 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: what happens when you use 
GROUP BY ColumnC, ColumnA % ColumnB

Comment: View is compiling correctly but cant create index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY ColumnC, ColumnA % ColumnB` ?

From your link:

> ..cannot contain... An expression on a column used in the GROUP BY clause, or an expression on the results of an aggregate.

I think this means you can't modulo on your group by columns. However, you should be able to do the expression in the GROUP BY and simply repeat in the select clause

Comment: yep I found it... the example from this msdn page does not work with SQL server :/